# How can I allow public login on my app registration in my Azure Tenant?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid

I'm trying to create an app hosted in Azure that (should) allow public login, as long as you have a Microsoft account. I don't care if it's a business or personal account. You just need to be able to log in. I'm creating a SPA and an API.

So I went to the Azure portal and created an app registration and configured the app reg to allow all users from within, or outside the organization with a valid personal or business Microsoft account.

Now the SPA is an Angular app and I use Damien Bod's OpenId library to log in. When I point the stsServer to my login endpoint ([https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tenant-id}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bmy-tenant-id%7D/v2.0)) and log in, all works fine, except when I log in using an account outside the organization (for example my personal account).

I get receive the following error:

`AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxx@xxxx.xxx' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'(App Name) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.`

Now the problem is that I simply don't want to add all these users, but allow them access to this app. How can I do that?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please let us known did external user registered in your azure ad tenant as a guest user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allow any account to sign in, you can't use your tenant-specific login endpoint.
You need to use the "common" endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`.
This allows login with any Azure AD / Personal Microsoft account.

Comment: Thanks, but then the issuer changes for every tenant. Is there a best practice to validate the issuer?

Comment: Issuer validation becomes a bit difficult at that point since every tenant has its own issuer URI. You could validate the format of the issuer URI though the usefulness is a bit questionable. You are validating token signatures anyway.

Comment: Your answer combined with this comment... It all comes together now... Thanks a bunch!